# When I send a POST request to newly-secured SpringBoot REST API I get a 403 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, request

I followed this tutorial:

https://dzone.com/articles/json-web-token-how-to-secure-spring-boot-rest-api

This should have added a login authorization system, at the end of the tutorial he sends a POST request with login credentials to the API to create that user, but when I try to do the same thing I get an error 403, forbidden.

The tutorial shows only the body of the request and doesn't show if any token is sent, but if you send the POST request to get back a token to then login, how can you send the token with the initial POST request?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
                return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
                "/v2/api-docs",
                "/swagger-resources",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/webjars/**"
        };

        public WebSecurityConfiguration(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
                this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;

        }

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

                httpSecurity.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()

                        .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()

                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/signup").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()

                        .and().addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))

                        .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))

                        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

                httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        }

        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
                authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }

        @Bean
        CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

                final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
                source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
                return source;
        }
}
```

Authentication Filter:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
            this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
            setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");
        }
        @Override

        public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
            try {

                com.example.project.domain.User creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), com.example.project.domain.User.class);
                return authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getUsername(), creds.getPassword(),new ArrayList<>()));
            }

        catch(IOException e) {

                throw new RuntimeException("Could not read request" + e);
            }

        }
        protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain, Authentication authentication)
        {
            String token = Jwts.builder()
                    .setSubject(((User) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 864_000_000))
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "SecretKeyToGenJWTs".getBytes())
                    .compact();
            response.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer " + token);
        }
    }
```

Authorization Filter:

```
    public class AuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

public AuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) { super(authenticationManager);}

protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)

        throws IOException, ServletException {

        String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if(header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer")) {

        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);

        return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = getAuthentication(request);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);

        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);

        }


private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if(token != null) {

        String user = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("SecretKeyToGenJWTs".getBytes())
        .parseClaimsJws(token.replace("Bearer",""))
        .getBody()
        .getSubject();

        if(user != null) {

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());

        }
        return null;
        }
        return null;
        }
}
```

UserDetailsImpl:

```
    @Component
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

        private UserRepository userRepository;

        public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
                this.userRepository = userRepository;
        }
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if(user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList());
        }
}
```

UserRepo:

```
 public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

UserController:

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

private UserRepository userRepository;

private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

public UserController(UserRepository userRepository, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        }

@PostMapping("/signup")
public void signUp(@RequestBody User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
        }
}
```

User:

```
    @Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

}
```

I am unable to access any pages of the API on browser as they just say 'There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access Denied'

This is what I expected, but I can't even access the login or signin pages, both giving 403 errors, clearly the site is restricting too much but I'm not sure why. Also, the API calls I send all fail, this could be a issue with my requests or the same issue with security.

When I send:

http://localhost:8080/users/signup

```
{
    "username": "timjenkins",
    "password": "TimoJenk20-"
}
```

I get the 403 error.

Edit:

Error when I go to /login only, others nothing appears in terminal.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read requestcom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.example.gambit2.security.AuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(AuthenticationFilter.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]

2021-11-09 21:44:22.701 ERROR 18092 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read requestcom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.example.gambit2.security.AuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(AuthenticationFilter.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar:9.0.54]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

No error appears in console when I try to send POST requests, but still get 403 returned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm stumped.
Thanks.

Comment: Post your code on github and send the link here ...

Comment: You need to enable the debug logging for Spring Security.
Add this like to application.properties file logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

Then add the output to your question

Comment: @ArthurKlezovich Hello, I have enabled debugging and added the error that appears in console when I try to navigate to /login. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to WebSecurityConfiguration :)

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().regexMatchers("^/users/signup$");
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, I added this and also changed the websecurity config to be 'users/signup' instead of just 'signup' for the POST requests permit all and also added one for GET but still get the same error. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I did find one interesting thing, when I now go to http://localhost:8080/signup (without /users/signup) I get a 404 instead of a 403.

Comment: I created a new controller called SessionsController and for some reason if I put the route to /signup it renders the page, and accepts POST requests. But I really need this to be in the UserController that accepts  /user/signup (forbidden), but just /signup works for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, just to let you know 
I managed to now send a POST request to /users/signup, then /login and then use that token response to /users with the json object responding successfully, thanks. I think it was your tip, and also I added /users/signup to whitelist and added login to permitall